# Flutter video player no audio

Tags: flutter, audio, video, codec

I created a simple video player in flutter. Many small size videos are working fine in this player.
But when i tried some high definition videos, sound is not working. (other video players playing this video with sound). So what may be the problem ? Do i need extra codecs to support this audios?